# Cloning A Page But Use A Different Widget Area

Tags: php, css, wordpress, widget, sidebar

I hope someone might be able to help me with this. I have a page layout that top half is page template and the text area at the bottom is a widgetised area.

Previously to replicate a look of a page we have copied and altered the page template, added a new widget area and called that into the new page.
However, I have tried to do this and I am not sure what I have done but I cant get it to call the correct widget area.
The original page is http://www.haylockpittman.co.uk/painting-and-decorating/ which is newpaint.php the template was copied, altered and uploaded to create http://www.haylockpittman.co.uk/builders-painters-decorators-and-refurbishment-contractors-surrey/ which is surreypaint.php

We created a new sidebar called "Surrey Paint" and widget area has been filled in with different text. However, despite everything looking like it is fine and calling up the correct sidebar it is still calling up the widget area from the original page.

Any help to perhaps point out where I am going wrong would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your new page is referencing the correct sidebar.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar

It is possible that the theme you started with might have that function buried within a few includes...so some refactoring might be needed.